# Java-Produce a list of products which has already expired based on the current date from text file

Tags: java, date, user-interface

i'm in making GUI application in netbeans for my college semester project (Market manager). we can add any product to the app and store the data as .txt file and file name is based on product code.
sample data in 1234.txt :

```
Product code : 1234
Name : Noodle
Price : $1000
Description : Instant noodle is not good for healthy
Expiry data : 12-01-2050
```

my question is how to read all file if there already added more of .txt file and read date in file and showing list of expired product to jtextArea as file name based on current date and button for remove all expired file.

```
private void okBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    String code = txtCode.getText();
    String name = txtName.getText();
    String price = txtPrice.getText();
    String expiry = txtExpiry.getText();
    String quantity = txtQuantity.getText();
    String description = txtDescription.getText();
    int quant = Integer.parseInt(quantity);

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++) {
            File file = new File("Product/"+code+i+".txt");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
                String content = "Code: " + code + i + "\r\nName: " + name + "\r\nPrice: RM." + price + "\r\nDescription: " + description + "\r\nExpiry Date: " + expiry;
                FileWriter data = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(data);
                bw.write(content);
                bw.close();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Product Added");

                txtCode.setText("");
                txtName.setText("");
                txtPrice.setText("");
                txtExpiry.setText("");
                txtQuantity.setText("");
                txtDescription.setText("");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The Product Code Already Added");
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

this code for adding product

Comment: That's  broad, what code do you have right now? How about using some  DB?

Comment: i already edit my question

Comment: and i still do nothing to jFrame for showing expired product
@RC. what is DB?
i still new for GUI program, and now i just second semester of my college

Comment: DB is a shorthand for database

Comment: my project required store to text file

Answer (score 1):

You start by **separating** responsibilities. You first create a **class** that represents a Product. In your current approach, you try to "model" a Product by a "set" of variables that somehow belong together.

Instead, create a class that has the corresponding fields; and a nice equals method for example.

Then you create a method that takes a String representing a filename. That method opens the file; reads the textual data and creates **one** Product object from that. Lets call that `readSingleProduct()`.

Next: create a method that takes a String representing a directory for example. That method checks for all the text files in that directory and calls `readSingleProduct()` in order create Product objects; and in the end, that method would return some `List<Product>`.

And then, finally, you build your UI code that receives such a List of Product objects, and uses that as *model* for the actual UI components.

And a hint: you **never** go with *empty* catch blocks. You should at least print the exception there; **ignoring** errors is always a super-bad idea!

Hope that gets you going!